# VBA error 1004 - select method of range class failed

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010, powerpoint, vba

First time poster, so if there is any formatting, or guidelines I failed to adhere to, please let me know so that I can fix it.

So I am basically asking the user for the file directory of the excel file, then I setup some variables (originally set at public as project variables, since these were being used and changed in other places). I have also added the lines to set these variables to nothing (just in case, I do not think that it should matter). I then set these variables to the excel file, workbook, and sheets that I want to access.

```
Dim filepath as String
filePath = CStr(fileDialog)              'ask file dir, set to string
Dim sourceXL As Variant                  'these three were orig project variables
Dim sourceBook As Variant
Dim sourceSheet As Variant
Dim sourceSheetSum As Variant

Set sourceXL = Nothing                    'set to nothing in case...?
Set sourceBook = Nothing
Set sourceSheet = Nothing
Set sourceSheetSum = Nothing

Set sourceXL = Excel.Application          'set to the paths needed
Set sourceBook = sourceXL.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Measurements")
Set sourceSheetSum = sourceBook.Sheets("Analysis Summary")

Dim measName As Variant                    'create variable to access later
Dim partName As Variant

sourceSheetSum.Range("C3").Select           'THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE

measName = sourceSheetSum.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value
sourceSheetSum.Range("D3").Select
partName = sourceSheetSum.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value
```

So I created two different sheet variables 'sourceSheets' and 'sourceSheetsSum', the code works if i use 'sourceSheets', but error 1004 occurs if i use 'sourceSheetsSum'. I have also tried the code with the variable 'sourceSheet' removed completely, in case that was overriding 'sourceSheetSum' for some reason.

I am fairly confident that the excel workbook and sheets exist and are being called correctly, since I ran a quick bit of code to loop through all the sheets in the workbook and output the names, shown below.

```
For j = 1 To sourceBook.Sheets.Count
Debug.Print (Sheets(j).name)
Next j
```

With the debug output of

> Measurements
>   Analysis Summary
>   Analysis Settings

So, does anyone have any ideas what this error could mean, or how I can possibly go about finding more about what the error actually is?

EDIT:
So I decided to add a bit to the listing of the sheet names, not sure if it will help at all.

```
For j = 1 To sourceBook.Sheets.Count
    listSheet(j) = Sheets(j).name
Next j    
Debug.Print (listSheet(2))    
Set sourceSheetSum = sourceBook.Sheets(listSheet(2))
```

The debug prints Analysis Summary, so I know that the sheet exists in the workbook, and there should not be any issues with a 'typo' in the names. 
The code still has the same error at the same line though.

deusxmach1na: I think you wanted me to change

```
Dim sourceXL As Variant                  
Dim sourceBook As Variant
Dim sourceSheet As Variant
Dim sourceSheetSum As Variant

Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Measurements")
```

To

```
Dim sourceXL As Excel.Application
Dim sourceBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheetSum As Worksheet

Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Measurements")
```

But this does not change the error, I remember I had it similar to that, and then changed it since I read that variant is like a catch all, not actually that solid on what variant is.

Comment: I would Dim your sheets specifically as Worksheets maybe and see what happens.  `Dim sourceSheetSum as Worksheet`  Actually, you may want to Dim everything with more specificity.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to select the sheet before you can select the range.

I've simplified the example to isolate the problem. Try this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub RangeError()

    Dim sourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheetSum As Worksheet

    Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sourceSheetSum = sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    sourceSheetSum.Select

    sourceSheetSum.Range("C3").Select           'THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE

End Sub
```

Replace Sheet1 and Sheet2 with your sheet names.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Using Variants is dangerous and can lead to difficult-to-kill bugs. Use them only if you have a very specific reason for doing so.

Comment: I can't believe you beat me by 13 secs on a 2 hour old question! +1 for speed ;-)

Comment: Nice! The stackoverflow Excel help desk is open for business!

Comment: @HeadofCatering Good Call! I hardly ever use Selects and forgot you have to Select the Sheet first.  Sigh, good ol' macro recorded code.

Comment: I have to say that Excel VBA error messages are really bad.  Why couldn't excel say "Error Selecting cells on non-current Sheet" or some such?  Sigh.

Comment: If error messages were that helpful, stack overflow wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

You can't select a range without having first selected the sheet it is in. Try to select the sheet first and see if you still get the problem:

```
sourceSheetSum.Select
sourceSheetSum.Range("C3").Select
```

Answer (score 4):

assylias and Head of Catering have already given your the reason why the error is occurring.

Now regarding what you are doing, from what I understand, you don't need to use `Select` at all

I guess you are doing this from VBA PowerPoint? If yes, then your code be rewritten as

```
Dim sourceXL As Object, sourceBook As Object
Dim sourceSheet As Object, sourceSheetSum As Object
Dim lRow As Long
Dim measName As Variant, partName As Variant
Dim filepath As String

filepath = CStr(FileDialog)

'~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set sourceXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

'~~> If not found then create new instance
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set sourceXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

Set sourceBook = sourceXL.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Measurements")
Set sourceSheetSum = sourceBook.Sheets("Analysis Summary")

lRow = sourceSheetSum.Range("C" & sourceSheetSum.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
measName = sourceSheetSum.Range("C3:C" & lRow)

lRow = sourceSheetSum.Range("D" & sourceSheetSum.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
partName = sourceSheetSum.Range("D3:D" & lRow)
```

Comment: Hi I have a related problem (sorry for hijacking). I am refactoring some code and moving it from the sheet to a module. It accesses the worksheet using the `Worksheets(name).Range` . It worked fine without a Select before I moved it to a module. Now I need to add a `Worksheet.Select` line before it to get it to work else it gives me a `'1004'`. In a few cases even that doesnt work. Any idea why moving the code created a problem and how to solve it without adding the line a million times. Sorry i am a VBA newbie.

Comment: @DPD : Yup... See this link ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Answer (score -1):

Removing the range select before the copy worked for me. Thanks for the posts.