# VBA Excel error when code is moved from worksheet to module

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a Excel file with multiple tabs. I have a worksheet with some code which is working fine. This code also refers to data on some "master" tabs. I need to duplicate this sheet so I moved the common functions from there to a module. Now I get a VBA `1004` error when trying to access a range on the same worksheet.

```
 Dim selectedRange As Range
 Set selectedRange = Worksheets(name).Range("A1", _
 Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)) 'Error Line
```

This code worked fine till I moved it to a module. It works if I put a

```
Worksheets(name).Select
```

before it, but I will have to do it too many times. Based on this query: [VBA error 1004 - select method of range class failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949893/vba-error-1004-select-method-of-range-class-failed/)
the code should work fine without a `.Select`. And it does as long as the code is within the worksheet. Why does moving code to a module create a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U use **Range and Rows properties without an object qualifier**. When used without an object qualifier, this properties are a shortcut for **ActiveSheet.Range / ActiveSheet.Rows.**

So the code does this:

```
Worksheets(Name).Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

But Worksheets(name) could be different from active sheet so better is:

```
Worksheets(Name).Range("A1", Worksheets(Name).Range("A" & Worksheets(Name).Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

In With-End With block:

```
With Worksheets(name)
      Set selectedRange = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

So it is ensured that the Range/Rows properties are applied on Worksheets(name) worksheet object.

Answer (score 0):

When you do things on a sheet, you do not really need explicit declarations to that sheet.

However when working on a module and interacting with other sheets, you need to specify which Sheet you want to work with. So *select* the sheet before you can *select* the range. To say, SELECT PARENT BEFORE YOU SELECT THE CHILDREN :) *Please note, following is just the logic explanantion. Not the exact code syntax.*

So I suggest you create the following worksheet variable and set your worksheet object that you need into that.

e.g.

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set WS = Sheets("Shee1")
Set selectedRange = WS.Range("A1", _
Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)) 'Error Line
```

Or else if you want to refer to all sheets, you may use each sheet's index

E.g. `ThisWorkBook.Sheets(i) 'i is an integer`
Then loop or whatever as it deems to your programme structure.

Further you do not have to use `Select`  on the worksheet to point to a range in that worksheet. As per above code you could set the worksheet and set the range you need to process. When optimizing VBA execution, `select` is usually a taboo. Also Excel 2007 does not retain the active sheet the way older versions used to.

Comment: You need to qualify _every_ range reference, so it becomes `WS.Rows.count`

Comment: It seems I missed out ur healthy comment and by the time I got back here, both my answer and your comment has been combined ;-)  thanks @ChrisNeilson